# Finding a specific Address in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to find specific address from a table.

Table as follows:

```
Staff: StaffNo(PK), StaffName, StaffAddress

SELECT StaffNo, StaffName
FROM Staff
WHERE StaffAddress LIKE  '%LONDON%'
```

Is the format correct?

What if I had another table as follows?

```
Registration: StaffNo(FK), BranchRegisteredIn
```

Is it possible to link the second table to the query to show the BranchRegisteredIn column using Joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT S.StaffNo, StaffName,BranchRegisteredIn
FROM Staff S
JOIN Registration R
ON S.StaffNo=R.StaffNo
WHERE StaffAddress LIKE  '%LONDON%'
```